# Phonegap Build - Media.play audio files in iOS 6 (iPhone 5) only playing on headphones

Tags: ios, cordova, html5-audio

I'm using the Phonegap Media api and things are not going too well. Even my most simple attempts fail, such as:

new Media(src).play();

The funny thing is however that audio works perfectly when the headphones are plugged in, but I can get no sound from the phone speakers.

I'm using phonegap build with phonegap 2.1.0 and testing on iOS 6.0.1 on an iPhone 5.

After a quite exhaustive search (I even tried Bing) I switched to html5 audio but the latency really sucks.

Any suggestions? I've read a few things about setting up an audio session? But could not find this in the PG build API docs and the examples appear to be using phonegap on xcode not PGBuild.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't add your own native code, or use a plugin that sets the audio session, then this is a bug in Phonegap Build. The audio session really needs to be set to 'playback'.

Comment: Turn your phone off silent (the physical switch on the side of your phone).

Comment: Chris: Yeah I'm starting to think that is the case.. I guess I'll have to figure out a way of just managing w/ html5 audio.